# Sql data to listview display

Tags: sql, vb.net, oracle, listview

I was pulling all this data from SQL and displaying it in an HTML table a windows form.  However needing that table to work with other parts of the form has caused me to have to change the table to something else.  I've decided to use a listview however I am not sure how to add the items I need from the SQL data.  Here is where I pull the data and it works just fine.

```
        STSQL = "SELECT SHOP_INV_VENDORS.VENDOR_PART_NO,SHOP_INVENTORY.WEIGHT,SHOP_INVENTORY.BUILD_NO,SHOP_INVENTORY.REVISION,SHOP_INV_VENDORS.VENDOR_PART_NO, SHOP_INVENTORY.DESCRIPTION, SHOP_INVENTORY.HOME_LOCATION, "
        STSQL = STSQL & "SHOP_INVENTORY.HOME_LOCATION_SUB, SHOP_INVENTORY.SI_KEY, SHOP_INVENTORY.SCRAP_FLAG, SI_MTIPART_INFO.STOCKROOM_QTY, "
        STSQL = STSQL & "SI_MTIPART_INFO.MIN_QTY,SHOP_INVENTORY.UOM,SHOP_INVENTORY.MTI_PART_NO,SHOP_INVENTORY.INV_TYPE "
        STSQL = STSQL & "FROM MPCS.SHOP_INVENTORY INNER JOIN MPCS.SI_MTIPART_INFO ON MPCS.SHOP_INVENTORY.INV_TYPE = MPCS.SI_MTIPART_INFO.INV_TYPE AND "
        STSQL = STSQL & "MPCS.SHOP_INVENTORY.MTI_PART_NO = MPCS.SI_MTIPART_INFO.MTI_PART_NO INNER JOIN "
        STSQL = STSQL & "MPCS.SHOP_INV_VENDORS ON MPCS.SHOP_INVENTORY.INV_TYPE = MPCS.SHOP_INV_VENDORS.INV_TYPE AND "
        STSQL = STSQL & "MPCS.SHOP_INVENTORY.MTI_PART_NO = MPCS.SHOP_INV_VENDORS.MTI_PART_NO "
        Select Case strCol
            Case "Part Number"
                STSQL = STSQL & "WHERE (SHOP_INVENTORY.MTI_PART_NO LIKE '%" & strString & "%') AND (SHOP_INVENTORY.SCRAP_FLAG <> 1) "
                STSQL = STSQL & "ORDER BY SHOP_INVENTORY.MTI_PART_NO"
            Case "Part Description"
                STSQL = STSQL & "WHERE (SHOP_INVENTORY.DESCRIPTION LIKE '%" & strString & "%') AND (SHOP_INVENTORY.SCRAP_FLAG <> 1) "
                STSQL = STSQL & "ORDER BY SHOP_INVENTORY.MTI_PART_NO"
            Case "Vendor Part Number"
                STSQL = STSQL & "WHERE (SHOP_INV_VENDORS.VENDOR_PART_NO LIKE '%" & strString & "%') AND (SHOP_INVENTORY.SCRAP_FLAG <> 1) "
                STSQL = STSQL & "ORDER BY SHOP_INVENTORY.MTI_PART_NO"
        End Select
        STSQL = "Select distinct NVL(WEIGHT,' ') AS WEIGHT,BUILD_NO,NVL(REVISION,' ') as REVISION,INV_TYPE,DESCRIPTION, HOME_LOCATION,HOME_LOCATION_SUB, SI_KEY, SCRAP_FLAG, STOCKROOM_QTY,MIN_QTY,UOM,MTI_PART_NO from (" & STSQL & ")"
        rsMPCS = MPCS_SELECT_SQL(UCase(STSQL), rsMPCS)
```

But now I need to display for example the results of MTI_PART_NO and DESCRIPTION in there own separate columns in listview.  I can create the columns but that's about as much as I know with listview.

When I was using HTML Tables I would just add `rsMPCS("MTI_PART_NO")` to the column.  Any help is appreciated.

**Update**
I did end up making a breakthrough but, if this is not the best option for what I am trying to do (explain in my comment below) does anyone have any better suggestions for my scenario?

Comment: The ListView is very ill suited for data displays: *everything* in them is string and there arent really columns, just subitem data `displayed as` columns.  If you fill a DataTable, you can display it in a DataGridView with one line of code using the DT as the DataSource

Comment: What would you recommend in this case.  I wanted something end user appealing, basically they will be searching for and displaying items.  Now it needs to be something they can click and select because they will be adding these items to there cart for submission to the stock room.  Like your typical product search, select, cart, checkout type setup.

Comment: *`If you fill a DataTable, you can display it in a DataGridView with one line of code using the DT as the DataSource`*